# Java object Get methods wait while object periodically refreshing itself

Tags: java, concurrency

Looking for the most correct / elegant way to have an objects GET methods block/wait while the object is internally refreshing itself. Sample code to simulate situation below.

Basically, when object is constructed, it goes off to a data source and populates its list items. The object is then used by multiple clients who regularly call the various GET methods to query the list of items.

Internally, the object keeps itself refreshed and up-to-date using a thread that periodically refreshes the list of items.

When the object is refreshing itself, all client GET calls should wait / block until the refresh has completed. Conversely, a refresh should not start if there is a client in the middle of calling a GET method.

I have tried a few different methods of achieving the desired functionality (such as notify / wait's and also countdown latches). However, am wondering what people think would be the 'most' correct / best / simplest way to achieve this?

Thanks Jab

```
public class MainResource {

    private List<Item> items;

    public MainResource() {
        this.items = new ArrayList<Item>();
        loadItems();
        startRefreshTimer();
    }

    public Item getSpecificItem(int i) {
        // This should wait if the items are being refreshed by the loadItems method
        return this.items.get(i);
    }

    public List<Item> getAllItems() {
        // This should wait if the items are being refreshed by the loadItems method
        return this.items;
    }

    private void loadItems() {
        // This should wait to execute if either the getSpecificItem() or getAllItems() methods are mid-execution
        this.items.clear();
        this.items.addAll(retrieveItems());
    }


    private List<Item> retrieveItems() {
        List<Item> ret = new ArrayList<Item>();

        // Do work to get all of the items.
        // Typically takes a few seconds.

        return ret;
    }

    private void startRefreshTimer() {
        // Every few minutes, reload all of the items.
        ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        Runnable periodicTask = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                loadItems();
            }
        };
        executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(periodicTask, 0, 120, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}
```

Comment: The most obvious option is to use javas *synchronize* mechanism: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html

Comment: A ReadWriteLock looks like a good candidate, since you have multiple readers which should be able to read concurrently, but should be blocked while the scheduled thread writes. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html. Not thet returning the list itself from getAllItems would ruin whatever strategy you might adopt, since any caller would be able to do what it wnats with the list that is supposed to be accessed concurrently in a safe way. Return a copy of the list.

Comment: The requirement that callers of the `get` methods need to block on refresh seems artificial and over-constraint, because there is no direct, causal relationship between an arbitrarily scheduled refresh and an access to an item. Put it another way, why the `get` should block at `t` if it wasn't at `t-epsilon`? Which invariant/type of consistency do you try to maintain? Is it possible *not* to block? That would considerably simplify the problem.

Comment: @JB Nizet, I like that approach. Just tried it out and seems clean. That said, Alexandre, I do appreciate your comment too in relation to avoiding blocking and that too would be good. However, for what I am doing, JB Nizet's solution is cleaner for me! Thanks everyone.